# DLL not found error when trying to use SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a small app coded in C# that works with a sqlite database, so when compiling I have the compiled exe + 2 dlls: SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll

On the machine where I compile this it works perfect (w7), but today i moved it to another machine with win XP and I got this when trying to execute it (the app has a try catch with a msgbox of the exception):

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'
>   The specified module could not be found.

All the dlls needed are in the same folder than the exe, what could be causing the error?

Is there any way I could compile or pack the dlls inside the exe?

Comment: What is this `SQLite.Interop.dll` for? In any case, check the *bitness*.

Comment: An interop DLL will usually contain the P/Invoke definitions, etc, or wrappers around them for managed code to use.  SQLite is a native app.

Comment: try to add reference of SQLite.Interop.dll to your application again.

Comment: Re-added reference, recompiled, moved into other machine, same problem. I am moving to delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest building your project for x86 processors and trying again.