# Error: SQLite.Interop.dll not found

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll

my Application consists of 2 Projects: App (with the EXE) and AppLib (A libary with different classes). I added SQLite with NuGet to the AppLib-Libary because all classes the handle the database-stuff are located there.

```
App
|--App
|--AppLib
```

The plan is, that my App-Project calls the and the database is filles with tables. When i build my project my App.exe and the AppLib.dll and all the SQLite-dlls are copied to App/bin/Debug.

But if i run my programm i get the error, that the SQLite.Interop.dll is missing. These dlls exists in AppLib:

```
App\AppLib\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
App\AppLib\bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll
```

But they are not copied to App\App\bin\Debug.

How do i manage this?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058048/dll-not-found-error-when-trying-to-use-sqlite-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with my problem. Adding the DLL as a reference is not possible and coding as X86 does not help ether.

Comment: Did you installed the SQLite package using this command?:  Install-Package System.Data.SQLite  (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)

Comment: Here (http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki) there is some answers, perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you installed Sqlite from nugets, you should have two folders who contains the Sqlite.Interop.dll in your debug or release folder.

..\bin\Debug\x86
or
\bin\Debug\x64

you should choose the right version depending to your application's architecture.

I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently and the key is in your first remark. There are multiple projects in your solution. If you use SqLite in a child project you need to install the package in your parent project as well otherwise the Interop DLL's can not be found.
I have not (yet) gone to the step of publishing so don't know what will happen at that step.

Answer (score 0):

SQlite.Interop is not referenceable, you have to:

1. In your VS project Add Existing File: Sqlite.Interop.dll actual
   location is .\bin\Debug\x86 or \bin\Debug\x64
2. Select properties and set Compilation Action in "Content" and copy to the output directory = "Always Copy"
3. Rebuild